# android spin / continuously rotate an image untill I command it to stop

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, progressdialog

I want to make a little fresh icon.

When I click on it, I want it to spin like a progress dialog, until my refresh is completed, then it must stop spinning.

How can I achieve this?

I tried with an animation like so:

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(30, 90,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);                
            refreshBtn.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

but that only rotates once or twice and then stops.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(30, 90,
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
rotateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
refreshBtn.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

Comment: OK and then how do I stop?

Comment: You would have an OnClickListener that, onClick, sets setRepeatCount(0);

Comment: @Zapnologica Call clearAnimation() on whichever View you called startAnimation().

Comment: @Zapnologica Yea, what makovkastar said works better :)