# rotate animation not stop

Tags: android, animation

Hello I want to be going non-stop how I do it

```
<rotate
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="3000"

    />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read up on [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Just use this code :)

```
     RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, BladeRotateAngle, 
     Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
     rotate.setDuration(5000);
     rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
     rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
     Object.startAnimation(rotate);
```

without line below , your animation stops after each loop:

```
     rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

so easy :))) ... Now if you need an animation with -->soft start<-- and infinite loop , use code below :

```
     final RotateAnimation[] rotate = {new RotateAnimation(0, 180, 
     Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f)};
     rotate[0].setDuration(3500);
     rotate[0].setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
     rotate[0].setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
     Object.startAnimation(rotate[0]);


     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {

             rotate[0] = new RotateAnimation(180, 540, 
             Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
             rotate[0].setDuration(4000);
             rotate[0].setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
             rotate[0].setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
             Object.clearAnimation();
             Object.startAnimation(rotate[0]);
         }
     } , 3500);
```

As you can see , the first animation effect , causes the Object to rotate smoothly (accelerately) from degree 0 to 180 , then the second animation causes the Object to rotate unaccelerated from degree 180 to 540 (one lape) infinitively :)

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you , accept it please :) ...@Haley Joel

Comment: Special thanks for the   rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380941/android-spin-continuously-rotate-an-image-untill-i-command-it-to-stop).
Try the following:

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(30, 90,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
rotateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
```

Then set the animation to the object you want to rotate:

```
yourObject.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

Comment: I did not change anything I want her to continue to spin without stopping

Comment: Sorry, it is difficult to help without knowing exactly what you want. You need to provide more code and more information describing what you have right now and what you want in the question.

Comment: My friend try the code at the top you will see that it spins and stops
But I do not want him to stop

Comment: 'what' is spinning? can you provide the code in your Activity or Fragment? You just provided the xml. Can you provide more to clarify exactly what is spinning and how you are using this xml? I can't try any code with just a pice of xml.

Comment: spins = Rotation 
I'm sorry I do not speak English well

Comment: I know what you mean by spinning. I meant to ask which object in your app do you want to spin. where is the code for that? Please provide more code. Thanks